# Prompt not working second time trying to add web app in Home Screen

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, service-worker, manifest.json

Trying adding a web app in home screen in chrome latest browser, its working properly first time accessing but not working second time that mean not prompting the message:

Below is my code:

1. created valid manifest json
2. include manifest file in index.html
3. and created service-worker.js

   ```
   self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
         event.respondWith(
           caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
             if (response) {
               return response;
             }          
             return fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
               return response;
             }).catch(function(error) {
               throw error;
             });
           })
         );
       });
   ```
4. register service worker in html page

   ```
   if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
       console.log("Will the service worker register?");
       navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
         .then(function(reg){
           console.log("Yes, it did.");
         }).catch(function(err) {
           console.log("No it didn't. This happened: ", err)
         });
     }
   ```

Scenario:

1. first time i hit the web page, its showing add screen prompt
2. added in home screen
3. uninstall the home screen page
4. i tried hit the web page again, its not showing add screen prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon on your home screen is just a shortcut to a chrome browser with added flavours (full screen, splash screen, orientation, etc).  So technically you just deleted the shortcut and not the app.

If you hit the kebab icon > info icon > Site Settings, you will be able to see that chrome has still saved it in the device.  The only way to really uninstall/delete it is by clicking on that Clear & Reset button which would make chrome think that the site is being visited the first time.

I think "issue" would be a nice feature for the chrome team to implement in the browser.  By "uninstalling" the PWA would clear and reset it as well.